# How to Capture or assign multiple conditions with Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

is there any way to capture or assign multiple conditions with Liquid?
I want to use that to manage my code since I will use the same conditions in many places.

```js
        {% capture brand_only %}
            template == 'index' 
            or template == 'page.topbright' 
            or template == 'collection.topbright' 
            or template == 'product.topbright'
            or template == 'page.sciencecan' 
            or template == 'collection.sciencecan' 
            or template == 'product.sciencecan'
            or template == 'page.zzzmoon' 
            or template == 'collection.zzzmoon' 
            or template == 'product.zzzmoon'
        {% endcapture %}

        {% if brand_only %}
            <div>CATEGORIES</div>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this (not tested):

```
{% if [brand_only] %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```